# Semigroup of operators: weak continuity at 0+ implies weak continuity at any t > 0

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, weak-convergence, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

Let ($E$, $d$) be a metric space. Consider the semigroup $\{P(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ of bounded linear operators on the Banach space $\hat{C}(E)$ of continuous real functions on ($E$, $d$) vanishing at infinity.
Given the following:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \downarrow 0} P_{t}f(x) = f(x), \quad \forall f \in \hat{C}(E), \forall x \in E
\end{equation}
How do we show that, for any $t>0$,
\begin{equation}
\lim_{h\downarrow 0} P_{t-h}f(x) = P_{t}f(x), \quad \forall f \in \hat{C}(E), \forall x \in E
\end{equation}
That is, left pointwise continuity. (I was able to show right pointwise continuity, simply by using the semigroup property.)

Comment: Have a look at proposition 1.3. on page 3 of [Engel & Nagel](https://www.fa.uni-tuebingen.de/research/publications/2006/a-short-course-on-operator-semigroups/A_Short_Course_on_Operator_Semigroups.pdf).